Kubernetes get pods How it can manage
C:\Users\HP>kubectl run sample-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80
error: unknown flag: --replicas
See 'kubectl run --help' for usage.

How to deal with this

kubectl run --replicas was removed as an option in Kubernetes 1.21.  I'd write a Deployment YAML file, check it into source control, and install it with kubectl apply -f; that's something you can repeat to redeploy the application, instead of depending on manual commands.

Issue may be related to the hyphen symbol, it may differs depends on encoding used in your operating system.

also, if you have old version of kubernetes, it may not support "replicas" flag
